# Events are not rendered till clicking "next" in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have cloned the AgendaWeekView and have created a new view with 3 days (AgendaThreeDayView). I made the necessary changes in the view, added a new button and everything is ok except one thing. The first time I navigate to the "3 day" view no events are on the calendar and I have to click either next or previous. After that, all the events are rendered in this view fine. It doesn't matter in which view I am when I click next or previous. Also I have checked that viewDisplay is triggered everytime as should be.

Comment: to problem can be reproduced if I am at the "3 day" view and I click the "today" button. Then it is not rendering the events as it should. If I navigate to the present day through next or previous it is fine.

Comment: actually the problem is reproduced when I click "today" no matter in which view I am when I click it. So I think that there is something different in rendering when you click "today" and the "next","previous" buttons. Anyone knows what's the difference between them so to be a hint in what place I should check my code?